# modifying the zsh shell word split

Tags: zsh

I am using the word split style shell (select-word-style shell). I like it in general but would like to split at forward slashes also, so that when I go forward/backward a word, if the word doesn't contain any /s, it completely skips over the word but if it does contain one or more slashes, it stops at the first slash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36):

`man zshall` `/forward-word` `/backward-word`

```
echo $WORDCHARS
*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>
WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'  ;# without /
```

Comment: +1 I wonder why this is not the default.  Paths are probably the single most used entity in a command line.

Comment: A more succinct version is `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\/]}`.

Comment: even shorter `WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}`

Comment: or `WORDCHARS=$WORDCHARS:s:/:`

Comment: is it only me or `;` isn't needed ? I would add `'"'` and `"'"` (single and double quotes) and `~`

Comment: This works in the default configuration, but the question assumes `select-word-style shell`, and that ignores `$WORDCHARS`.

Comment: I personally use WORDCHARS='_'

Comment: @SamuelCoskey indeed this is more consistent with others character classes like regex word characters \w