# How can I have two keystrokes to delete to either a slash or a word in zsh?

Tags: zsh

### Bash behaviour

I've just migrated from `bash` to `zsh`. In `bash`, I had the following line in `~/.inputrc`.

```
"\e\C-?": unix-filename-rubout
```

Hence, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> would delete back to the previous slash, which was useful for editing paths.

Separately, `bash` defaults to making <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>  delete to the previous *space*, which is useful for deleting whole arguments (presuming they don't have spaces). Hence, there two slightly *different* actions performed with each key combination.

### Zsh behaviour

In `zsh`, both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> do the same thing. They both delete the previous word, but they are too liberal with what constitutes a word-break, deleting up to the previous `-` or `_`. Is there a way to make `zsh` behave similarly to `bash`, with **two independent actions**? If it's important, I have `oh-my-zsh` installed.

Comment: Do you want to change zsh's definition of what constitutes a word? If so: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split Or do you want to define a new command with a different definition of word?

Comment: @Gilles I guess a combination of both. In bash, I'd use the two distinct commands regularly: i.e. delete to the last `/` and delete to the last ` `. They have different functions.

Comment: @Gilles So yes, that link works for my `bash`-like Alt+Backspace behaviour, but I'd still like the (different) `bash`-like Ctrl+w behaviour, i.e. delete to last space.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit: The next google result after your question was this one with same solution : [zsh: make ALT+BACKSPACE stop at non-alphanumeric characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313806/zsh-make-altbackspace-stop-at-non-alphanumeric-characters)

This answer was provided by `/nick FoH` from #zsh on freenode.

```
backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-kill-word
    zle -f kill
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[^?' backward-kill-dir
```

This way you can use `ctrl+w` for deleting a Word (in vim lingo) and `alt+bkspc` to delete a word

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for taking the time to investigate and answer.

Comment: Re Google: except I asked my question nine months ago, and they asked theirs less than a month ago.

Comment: time is just a social construct man!.. but seriously, fair point.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It seemingly makes ^w and meta-bs act in the same way.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, it may be because your `WORDCHARS` is empty, so perhaps you want to try setting it explicitly instead: `local WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=&;!#$%^(){}<>'` (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200998/4545777)

Answer (score 50):

A similar question was asked here: [zsh: stop backward-kill-word on directory delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444951/zsh-stop-backward-kill-word-on-directory-delimiter)

and a workable solution given: add these settings to your zshrc:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, none of those answers work for me. (Specifically, the one you quoted makes no change.) Possibly, it's because I have `oh-my-zsh` installed. In any case, this doesn't seem to address the two different functions and key bindings as per my question. (And if my question were it dupe it should be closed as a dupe. Which it is not.)

Comment: You need to tweak WORDCHARS variable. In zsh it's easy `vared WORDCHARS`

Comment: It would only be a duplicate if we matched it against an answered question in *this* forum.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Oh yes, apologies, I didn't notice I'd swapped SE sites.

Comment: @Jshura No, as per the question, I'd like two different functions, which is possible in `bash`.

Comment: @Sparhawk it didn't work for me when I had command syntax highlighting enabled for some reason. I disabled it and now it works (anyway it makes the prompt laggy - I can live without it).

Comment: worked great for me on my mac (bash to zsh). Key bindings can be defined in the preferences of the terminal app

Comment: Don't forget that **Terminal.app** traditionally presumes that you need to use `Option` to get to certain common characters (like "@") - this is NOT such a big issue for modernm keyboard layouts, and I wish that its **Preferences** checkbox **"Use Option as Meta key"** was _checked_ by default! Because now we need to ALWAYS CHECK IT instead for e.g. Alt-Backspace or Alt-arrows to work as expected. 

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on [JunkMechanic's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319854/100270), I wanted that

- existing zsh shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>) works as in zsh defaults
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-based shortcuts (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>) work similarly, but "finer grained", e.g. up to the closest `/`

Here's what I use now:

```
# Alt+Backspace
backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-kill-word
    zle -f kill  # Ensures that after repeated backward-kill-dir, Ctrl+Y will restore all of them.
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[^?' backward-kill-dir


# Alt+Left
backward-word-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-word
}
zle -N backward-word-dir
bindkey "^[[1;3D" backward-word-dir

# Alt+Right
forward-word-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle forward-word
}
zle -N forward-word-dir
bindkey "^[[1;3C" forward-word-dir
```

For details on the `zle -f kill`, see [Zsh - pasting text killed in a custom widget only works for last word, can that be fixed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659206/zsh-pasting-text-killed-in-a-custom-widget-only-works-for-last-word-can-that/659208)

Answer (score 3):

I achieved your desired result by sticking the following in `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`:

```bsh
# Use bash-like word definitions for navigation and operations
autoload -Uz select-word-style
select-word-style bash

# Use C-w to kill back to the previous space
zle -N backward-kill-space-word backward-kill-word-match
zstyle :zle:backward-kill-space-word word-style space
bindkey '^W' backward-kill-space-word
```

This has an advantage over other answers by not limiting the target delimiter of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to `/`; for example, it will delete back to `-`, as well. Still, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> will delete back to the previous space. This is more `bash`-like than other answers.

I am using `zsh` 5.8 on macOS, without `oh-my-zsh` or any other configuration framework.

Reference: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-backward_002dkill_002dword_002dmatch

---

***Bonus**: The following makes `zsh` even more `bash`-like:*

```bsh
# Use C-u to kill to the beginning of the line
bindkey '^U' backward-kill-line

# Use C-x C-e to edit the current command line in $VISUAL
autoload -Uz edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey '^X^E' edit-command-line
```

Answer (score 1):

##### `bindkey '^[^?' vi-backward-kill-word`

---

As far as I can tell, its effect on `Meta-BackSpace` is the same as with the [answer suggested by @thomas-dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258661/38601), and it's a oneliner rather than two ;-). However, this **only** affects Meta-BS. If you are looking for the full bash-like behavior with Meta-(Left/Right) navigation then `select-word-style` is the right way.

*(Footnote: the `select-word-style`*-thing* is documented in `man zshcontrib` but they are all but incomprehensible to me. `vi-backward-kill-word` is documented in `man zshzle`.)*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this in nh2's answer

- alt + left/right arrow to move
- alt + delete/w for deleting word forward/backward

---

```
# Alt+Delete
forward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle kill-word
}
zle -N forward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[[3;3~' forward-kill-dir

# Alt+w
backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-kill-word
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[w' backward-kill-dir

# Alt+Left
backward-word-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-word
}
zle -N backward-word-dir
bindkey "^[[1;3D" backward-word-dir

# Alt+Right
forward-word-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle forward-word
}
zle -N forward-word-dir
bindkey "^[[1;3C" forward-word-dir
```