# Pasting text killed in a custom widget only works for last word, can that be fixed?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I'm using answers from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258656/58016) so that I can cut longer/shorter parts of text when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> respectively. Specifically I have this in my `.zshrc` to add the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> behavior (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is built-in)

```bsh
backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=''
    zle backward-kill-word
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[^?' backward-kill-dir
```

This works fine for killing text, but then pasting it doesn't work as expected. Let's say I have this text:

```
A quick brown fox
```

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> four times and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, the entire text will be cut and then pasted back. But if I have this text:

```
a-quick-brown-fox
```

and I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> four times and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, it will cut the text as expected but only paste

```
a-
```

How can I make the latter also paste the entire text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in kill widgets replace the previous content of the internal clipboard unless the previous command was also a kill action. You need to indicate that your custom widget is a kill action by calling the [`zle` builtin](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-defining-widgets) to set the `kill` flag.

```
backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=''
    zle backward-kill-word
    zle -f kill
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[^?' backward-kill-dir
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!