# zsh: make ALT+BACKSPACE stop at non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: command-line, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In `zsh` by default, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> seem to have exactly same effect.

How can I keep <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> as it is, and change <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> so that it stops at non-alphanumeric characters.

ie, when the cursor is at the end of following command: `echo /aaa/bbb/ccc`, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> should leave `echo`, while pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> should leave `echo /aaa/bbb/`.

## UPDATE

based on answer from `@Thomas Dickey`, I have added the following to my `.zshrc`:

```
 my-backward-delete-word () {
    local WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?+;'
    zle backward-delete-word
 }
 zle -N my-backward-delete-word

 bindkey    '\e^?' my-backward-delete-word
```

Now the command line editor behaves differently than I expected.

For example, the single quote character `'` is not enumerated in my `WORDCHARS`, so when I press <kbd>Alt+BackSpace</kbd>, the `backward-delete-word` should stop at `'`.

This works in in first example, but not in the second:

```
$ echo 'asdf'
$ echo '

$ echo '=asdf'
$ echo '=
$
```

in the second example, I had `echo '=` left on the commandline. After I have pressed <kbd>Alt+BackSpace</kbd> second time, everything was eaten, including `echo`. I would have expected only `=` should have been eaten, because it should have stopped at `'`.

Why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually I don't see this listed in zsh bindings, but if `bindkey` shows it for *you*, then it's configurable by binding to a function that you define.

Working from my answer in

- *[How can I delete to a slash or a word in zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258656/how-can-i-delete-to-a-slash-or-a-word-in-zsh)*, I found this:
- *[zsh: stop backward-kill-word on directory delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444951/zsh-stop-backward-kill-word-on-directory-delimiter)*, which pointed to
- *[Re: backward kill](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2001/msg00870.html)*, giving this example by Will Yardley:

```
    i use this bit contributed by someone on the list (Oliver Kiddle); check
    the archives from Mon, Oct. 8 for more info on this:

    tcsh-backward-delete-word () {
      local WORDCHARS="${WORDCHARS:s#/#}"
      zle backward-delete-word
    }

    i have it bound to control-W with:
    bindkey '^W' tcsh-backward-delete-word

    but you can change that obviously.

    i think that's what you're looking for, no?

    the '$WORDCHARS' variable is how zsh determines word boundaries so you
    could add '/' to that globally, however this might affect other things
    you want to leave it for, so i prefer this function.
```

- which leads to examples of using `$WORDCHARS` in *[modifying the zsh shell word split](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split)*, as well as the wiki
- [zle:bindkeys](http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys)

So: you can use `$WORDCHARS` as a local variable in your own function, defining words as you want, and binding it to an arbitrary key.

When you define your function, don't forget to add it as a *keymap*:

```
zle -N tcsh-backward-delete-word
```

Comment: would you mind adding a working example for `alt+backspace`? When I tried your example, I get: `No such widget tcsh-backward-delete-word`.

Comment: The example assumes you have defined a function `tcsh-backward-delete-word` (with `$WORDCHARS` set to the characters you want for "works").

Comment: - that's what I did. And I get the above mentioned error: `no such widget ...`.

Comment: please see my update. I have also stared a bounty.