# Proper way of setting word separators in `zsh`

Tags: bash, zsh

What I tried:

[solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444951/zsh-stop-backward-kill-word-on-directory-delimiter)

[solution 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48577/modifying-the-zsh-shell-word-split)

[solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202521/deleting-word-like-bash-in-zsh-autoload-is-not-working)

Nothing works.

In other word, setting `WORDCHARS` or using `select-word-style bash` in `zshrc` has no effect whatsoever.

Is it possible to set the word separators to have the `ctrl-w` behavior like in `bash` at all?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this today, setting `$WORDCHARS` did work for me.

What I wanted to do was have the `/` and `_` chars be treated as word separators. To do that, I had to remove those from `$WORDCHARS`.

```
WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/_}
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect for me

Comment: What is `$WORDCHARS` set to?

Comment: it outputs nothing

Comment: That might be an issue - mine is `*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>` by default. without removing any. Try setting and modifying that in your `.zshrc`

Comment: That's not working. Any setting of `WORDCHARS` has no effects. Right now I have `backward-kill-dir () {
    local WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS/\/}
    zle backward-kill-word
    zle -f kill
}
zle -N backward-kill-dir
bindkey '^[^?' backward-kill-dir`